# Option groups with associated tables

Tags: cakephp, collections, cakephp-3.x

I am using option grouping in a form in cakephp 3.
I am using this find:

```
$seasons = $this->Episodes->Seasons
            ->find('all')
            ->combine('id','season','show_id')
            ->toArray();
```

The result is *nearly* what I need:

```
[
    (int) 269 => [
        (int) 784 => (int) 1
    ],
    (int) 270 => [
        (int) 785 => (int) 1,
        (int) 786 => (int) 2,
        (int) 787 => (int) 3
    ]
]
```

But instead of grouping by the show_id, I would prefer to broup by the show's name, that is, access the table that is associated by the show_id field and get the name from there, resulting in

```
[
    'some show' => [
        (int) 784 => (int) 1
    ],
    'another show' => [
        (int) 785 => (int) 1,
        (int) 786 => (int) 2,
        (int) 787 => (int) 3
    ]
]
```

I tried:

```
$seasons = $this->Episodes->Seasons
            ->find('all')
            ->contain('Shows')
            ->combine('id','season','Shows.name')
            ->toArray();
```

but that doesn't work. (Shows.name seems empty, resulting in no grouping at all.) How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: It can be done with a closure.

```
    $seasons = $this->Episodes->Seasons
            ->find('all')
            ->contain('Shows')
            ->combine('id','season',function($season) {return $season->show->name;})
            ->toArray();
```

gives the desired result.

Comment: Using dot notated paths works too, but it should be `show.name`, which reflects the actual data structure. Collections don't know about ORM conventions and stuff.

Comment: @ndm: Maybe you should post this as an answer instead of a comment, so that I could set it as accepted answer. I am a bit reluctant to accept my own answer...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with accepting your own answers - given that they are actually correct of course. If you add the dot notation hint and maybe a [**link to the docs**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake\Collection\Collection::combine) people should have everything they need to solve similar problems.